# Django - CKeditor dynamic image size based on client device

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-imagekit, django-ckeditor, django-filer

I'm trying to develop a blog style website and I use Django as web framework, CKeditor as wygiwys and Filer for file management (linked with CKeditor with django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer).
It's all working, but the problem is that I can't control the image size for the images used inside the posts, I'd like to serve them based on user's device (smaller on mobile, larger on desktop, etc..).
I have no idea how to do that, any ideas? thanks

**EDIT:**
An idea would be: the CKeditor makes the html block and then send it to the client with the filer image src (like 'media/uploads/46813413/12'), then again from the server intercept the request to the filer media and send a resized image based on the the device that made the request. But is it possible to manage the filer requests?

Comment: Hi Davide, what have you attempted so far for controlling image sizes? Do you have any of your code you can share?

Comment: Hi! Right now i just serve the full size image to the client. For the images that are not in the post content i use easy_thumbnail, but it can't be used in the post content since CKeditor return a string of html code. I'm thinking about "intercepting" the user request to the filer resource and then give to the client a custom size image, but I don't know how to implement it (and if it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in the settings.py file. Specify the `width & height as 100%` like below,

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': '100%',
        'width': '100%',
    },
}
```

If you want to more or less height, you can use like `'height': '200'`.

You can do much more configuration with `ckeditor`, refer to [official documentation](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)